# Parsing Windows tasklist output in Java

Tags: java, string, windows, split, tasklist

I am trying to build an array of processes running on my machine; to do so I have been trying to use the following two commands:

```
tasklist /fo csv /nh        # For a CSV output
tasklist /nh                # For a non-CSV output
```

The issue that I am having is that I can not properly parse the output.

**First Scenario**

I have a line like:

```
"wininit.exe","584","Services","0","5,248 K"
```

Which I have attempted to parse using `"".split(",")`, however this fails when it comes to the process memory usage - the comma in the number field willl result in an extra field.

**Second Scenario**

Without the non-CSV output, I have a line like:

```
wininit.exe                    584 Services                   0      5,248 K
```

Which I am attempting to parse using `"".split("\\s+")` however this one now fails on a process like `System Idle Process`, or any other process with a space in the executible name.

> How can I parse either of these output such that the same split index will always contain the correct data column?

Comment: Did you try to use a CSV-parser instead of just splitting on the comma? CSV is typically well defined, and good parsers correctly interpret the quotes and do not just split at every comma.

Comment: I would like to accomplish this using as few external libraries as possible, preferable none at all. The task seems simple enough, just wondering what the best approach would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse a string, always prefer the most strict formatting. In this case, **CSV**. In this way, you could process each line with a regular expression containing FIVE groups:

```
private final Pattern pattern = Pattern
    .compile("\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\",\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\",\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\",\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\",\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"");

private void parseLine(String line) {

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

    if (!matcher.find()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid format");
    }

    String name = matcher.group(1);
    int pid = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    String sessionName = matcher.group(3);
    String sessionId = matcher.group(4);
    String memUsage = matcher.group(5);

    System.out.println(name + ":" + pid + ":" + memUsage);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Yay java escapement... Had to mess with the regex a bit. Editing in the non-ruby regex with some of my own edits to make a complete and working answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a StringTokenizer class instead of split.  You use the `"` delimiter and expect the delimiter to be returned.  You can then use that delimiter to provide field separation.  For instance,

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, "\"", true);

State state = NONE;

while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String t = st.nextToken();
    switch(state) {
       case NONE:
          if ("\"".equals(t)) {
             state = BEGIN;
          }
          // skip the ,
          break;
       case BEGIN:
          // Store t in which entry it correspond to.
          state = END;
          break;
       case END:
          state = NONE;
          break;
    }
}
```

Each token will be stored within its respective data set and you can then process that information for each Process.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and seems to work.

```
 public void parse(){
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = runtime.exec("tasklist -fo csv /nh");
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println();
                for (String column: line.split("\"")){
                    if (!column.equals(",")&& !column.equals("")){
                        System.out.print("["+column+"]");
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```